# Merge is not showing Values, though I have a common column in 2 data frames

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am a beginner in python as well as in Pandas and I want to extract lines which are not matching in both the sheets based on column called "KeyValue" and that column value is the concat of columns ('WeekStartDate','EmployeeName','ScheduleType','Day1','CenterCode') in both the sheets.

However I am getting no merged values, it shows values from both DFs on top of each other despite having common Column & value in it. here is my code and result. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('Vinay1.csv')
#print(df.info())

df1 = pd.read_csv('Maddy1.csv')
#print(df1.info())

Test1 = pd.merge(df, df1, on='KeyValue', how='outer')
#Test1.to_csv('MergedData1.csv')

print(Test1)
Test1.to_csv('MergedData2.csv')

================================================================


Output:
     Unnamed: 0_x  RowID  ...  WeekStartDate_y           Day1_y
0             0.0    1.0  ...              NaN              NaN
1             1.0    2.0  ...              NaN              NaN
2             2.0    3.0  ...              NaN              NaN
3             3.0    4.0  ...              NaN              NaN
4             4.0    5.0  ...              NaN              NaN
..            ...    ...  ...              ...              ...
194           NaN    NaN  ...       10-01-2022  11:00AM-05:00PM
195           NaN    NaN  ...       10-02-2022  10:00AM-05:00PM
196           NaN    NaN  ...       10-01-2022  09:00AM-05:00PM
197           NaN    NaN  ...       10-02-2022  10:00AM-05:00PM
198           NaN    NaN  ...              NaN              NaN

[199 rows x 28 columns]
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

**Note:** here are the two CSV sheets that I am using to compare & merge. I was using

**Update:**
I tried a lot, however, could not share the sample csv and result csv here :(
Hence, please find the sample data & result by clicking below the G-drive link.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10wkH8LIHwb7kZk2TF-c-V4ZZb9HXTCa_?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide a constructor of a sample of your dataframe to reproduce your problem. Also, kindly read [ask].

Comment: Would you happen to be asking about the appearance of the NaN values in your dataframe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your formatting isn't helpful: If I try to copy and paste the data of a CSV-file I'll get 1 long line of data, no linebreaks. (Please have a little trust in edits of experienced users.)

Comment: Look closely at `09-12-2022Christi HallSchedule10:00AM-03:30PM81416` and `09-12-2022Christi Hallschedule10:00AM-03:30PM81416` --> `...HallS...` vs. `...Halls...`. Thus no `KeyValue` matches and since `how="outer"` you'll get 2 disjunct pieces.

Comment: @Timus - Love you so much Man... I have been scratching my head since last night and got nothing... Finally, my project is completed... Thank you so much, bro... .. you made my day...